# json.dumps making many arrays of objects rather than typical json format

Tags: python, json, serialization, formatting

trying to create a json file containing the VM's from an import function in a python module. the export is an api call iterator that walks through results. I'm trying filter the vast majority of the keys in the returned json object to just list the hostname key as "vmName" to match another file.

```
import json
from tenable.io import TenableIO

#api stuff
tio-TenableIO()
wr = open('tioasset.json','w')


result = []
for asset in tio.exports.assets():
        for a in asset['hostnames']:
            new_data= {'vmName' : a},
            result.append(new_data)

wr.write(json.dumps(result, indent = 4))
```

This works and is iterating through the results and making a new json file containing just the key "vmName" with the value from "hostnames" in assets. However, the format is wonky and is giving me several arrays containing objects:

```
[
    [
        {
            "vmName": "aaa111"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "vmName": "bbb222"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "vmName": "ccc333"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "vmName": "ddd444"
        }
    ],
]
```

This doesn't look right, and I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to look like a normal json file that should presumably look like this:

```
[
 {
  "vmName": "aaa111"
 },
 {
  "vmName": "bbb222"
 },
 {
 "vmName": "ccc333"
 },
 {
 "vmName": "ddd444"
 },
```

]

Comment: check whether 'result' contains data in correct format

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
result.append(new_data)
```

is inside two for loops so you're appending a list to a list

try moving your empty list as so:

```
final_result = []
for asset in tio.exports.assets():
    result = []
    for a in asset['hostnames']:
        new_data= {'vmName' : a},
        result.append(new_data)
 final_result.extend(result)
```

OR, you might get away with what you have by just changing to

```
result.extend(new_data)
```

extend adds to the list rather than make a list of lists. I can't test this but one some form of this should work